# How to style an RSS feed similar to YouTube?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview, interface-builder

[image]Hey everyone,

I'm looking to display multiple items in view of an iOS app. Typically I would use UITableView to accompli[image]sh this but now I'm looking for something a little fancier. The appearance that I hope to replicate is that of YouTube on iOS systems. A picture of this [youtube] is attached. I am particularly interested in how each video entry is styled. The box around the entry, the background. My guess as to how YouTube does this is through multiple UIViews or stylish UITableViewCell. Any class or framework recommendation would be of great assistance. I have spent hours searching google and stackoverflow to no avail.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is very likely that they use a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell.

Comment: Cool. Any idea as to what property of UITableViewCell will give the square container each video link has?

Comment: It isn't a property. You'll have to either add a graphic to the cell's contentView or subclass and override drawRect.

Comment: Thanks. After manipulation of the UITableView, it appears that you are spot on with regards to how they do this. The issue that I have now is creating space to the left and right of the cell. When I try to alter the table frame, I end up with plan white space covering up the cell. Wh

Comment: I have attached an image of what happens when I try to alter the frame of UITableView to get the effect that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mimic the style of the YouTube app, I just subclassed UITableViewController with an initialized style of UITableViewStyleGrouped.